# How to manually document C typedef struct with Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

This is the first time I'm using Sphinx. I'm trying to document a C API manually, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the right way.

I wasn't able to document

```c
typedef struct
{
    int i;
    float f;
} mytype1_t;
```

without breaking it into two parts and also introducing a tag:

```
.. c:type:: struct _mytype1 mytype1_t

.. c:struct:: _mytype1

    .. c:var:: int i
    .. c:var:: float f
```

Similarly, for

```c
typedef enum {ENUMERATOR1, ENUMERATOR2} mytype2_t;
```

the best thing I could reach was

```
.. c:type:: enum _mytype2 mytype2_t

.. c:enum:: _mytype2

    .. c:enumerator:: \
        ENUMERATOR1
        ENUMERATOR2
```

Are these correct?